# Node Teaser Acting like Full Node

Tags: views, theming

I have got a problem.  I have been upgrading my site from Drupal 6 to 7 and I've reached about 75% of the way.  I have updated all my 3rd party modules and custom modules and while I was configuring some setting for my 3rd party modules, like Taxonomy Image, I noticed that in my front page the teasers where displaying a view that I wanted to embed only in the full node view.

I looked at my node.tpl.php, which is where I was adding the view and the if/else for the view looks good, but for some reason, when I debugged it, the if ($teaser) is not the one that it is going to when I load the front page, it is actually going to the else.

This is the code in my node.tpl:

```
  <div class="clearfix">
    <?php if (!empty($content['links'])): ?>
      <div class="links"><?php print render($content['links']); ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if($teaser): ?> 
            <?php print render($content['comments']); ?>
        <?php else: ?>
        <!--    //Add the comments and related_by_term block to the footer_wrapper div -->
            <div id="footer_wrapper">
                <?php print render($content['comments']); ?>
                <?php $related_by_term_block = block_load('views', 'related_by_term-block_1');
                    $block_content = _block_render_blocks(array($related_by_term_block));
                    $build = _block_get_renderable_array($block_content);
                ?>
                    <div id="blackborder_related_by_term_block">
                <?php 
                    print render($build); 
                ?>
                    </div>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

I have no idea if any of the 3rd party modules I have are getting in the way.  This is the list of my 3rd party modules:

1. FLAG
2. DATE
3. CAPTCHA
4. MOLLOM
5. ADVANCED HELP
6. BETTER FORMATS
7. FLAT COMMENTS
8. FORWARD
9. SEARCH CONFIGURATION
10. SHARED EMAIL
11. VOTING API
12. WYSIWIG
13. AUTHOR PANE
14. PUBLISH CONTENT
15. WORKFLOW
16. THEMEKEY
17. CHAOS TOOL SUITE (CTOOLS)
18. VIEWS
19. ENTITY API
20. VIEWS BULK OPERATIONS (VBO)
21. VIEWS ATTACH (EVA)
22. SIMILAR BY TERMS
23. ADVANCED FORUM
24. RULES
25. LIBRARIES API
26. GRAMMAR PARSER
27. GRAMMAR PARSER LIBRARY
28. HTML PURIFIER
29. TOKEN
30. INVITE
31. FIVESTAR

Any input would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Debug $view_mode, what do you get?

Comment: $teaser is an 'undefined' which is what's really odd. $view_mode say's 'full'.

Comment: Go to your content type (in the CMS) and see if it has a 'teaser' view mode.

Comment: Its under 'Manage display'.

Comment: Yeah, it is does have a teaser view mode.  I just checked the article node type.

Comment: You said this was a view, is your view set to the right view mode?

Comment: Actually, I think this should not have anything to do with the view at all, because, the problem is, my teasers are being rendered as full nodes.  Something is messing with the way it should be rendered.  In the front page, normally, I have all my nodes displayed in teaser view, but now, it is rendering the full view.

Comment: I figured it out!!

Answer (score 0):

It is the Advanced Forum module that is causing the problem.  Once I disabled it, it displayed as a teaser.  Now, I need to figure out just why.  Thanks for your help, Alex, really appreciate it.

Comment: Well done, no worries! ;-)